# Sound off if you came here from TAM!

Tags: discussion

I handed out -shirts to folks that signed up from TAM.  I was hoping that some of you would say hello, as well as get right into the answering of questions. I know that I spoke to each one of you, so if you have any questions, please feel free to use this post as a sort of miscellaneous dumping ground.  Welcome to another area for skeptical activism.

Comment: Have they found Meta yet?  Maybe that could be a topic for your next skepticamp presentation? How to get the most out of a skeptical activism site.